# Redirect to Login upon Session TimeOut

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-timeout

I've used this approach below in which you will be automatically directed to the login page upon session timeout, but the problem is that, even if you're doing something you will be redirected.

[AutoRedirect](http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource9-how-to-do-auto-logout-and-redirect-to-login-page-when-session-expires-using.aspx)

Is there any approach for handling session timeout?

BTW I'm using ASP.Net C#

Thanks! (^_^)b

Comment: if you are dong something which doesnt require server interaction then you are bound to get redirected

Answer (score 1):

User following values in web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="1" defaultUrl="~/" />
</authentication>

<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" timeout="1">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Here I have used default session provider but you can use your own custom session provider and the timeout value you want, but should be same in forms tab and sessionState tag.

It is working for me as you are expecting.

Regards,
Nitin Joshi

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont use form authentication. @_@

Answer (score 0):

**Try following code:**

```
if(session["YourSessionName"].ToString()=="" or Session["YourSessionName"] == null)

{

Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That auto redirect doesn't look like a good idea.

The Session_End event (in global.asax) will fire when your session ends and you can redirect to a login page there; however, bear in mind that it will *only* fire if you're using In-Process session state, which is the default.

If you use one of the out-of-process state options (State Server or SQL), Session_End does not fire and you will have to use an HttpModule; try this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21156/ASP-NET-HttpModule-for-handling-session-end-with-S

Hope that helps